# Accessing the Element behind head of Queue Without Acknowledgment in RabbitMQ

Tags: go, rabbitmq

In one of my use case, I need a priority Queue. Messages in the queue should be prioritized as per message values. So we have picked **RabbitMQ**.

Now Suppose a consumer picked head message at Queue, and somehow it failed to acknowledge or not still in position to acknowledge(as post acknowledge, message would be dequeued), and a different consumer want to pick message behind the head.

Is this scenario possible in RabbitMQ design.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#channel-qos-prefetch. It seems the solution.